# Redis3.0.3 cluster warning: wrong element type nil at 0 (expected array)

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

when I create redis cluster, I met errors as follows:
[pirate@zhangbincan src]$ /home/zhangbincan/tools/ruby/ruby-2.2.2/ruby redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 192.168.1.114:6379 192.168.1.114:6780 192.168.1.114:6381 192.168.1.114:6382 192.168.1.114:6383 192.168.1.114:6384

> > > Creating cluster
> > >       Connecting to node 192.168.1.114:6379: OK
> > >       /usr/local/ruby2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis3.0.0/lib/redis.rb:182: warning: wrong element type nil at 0 (expected array)
> > >       /usr/local/ruby2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis3.0.0/lib/redis.rb:182: warning: ignoring wrong elements is deprecated, remove them explicitly
> > >       /usr/local/ruby2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis3.0.0/lib/redis.rb:182: warning: this causes ArgumentError in the next release
> > >       /usr/local/ruby2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis3.0.0/lib/redis.rb:182: warning: wrong element type nil at 18 (expected array)
> > >       /usr/local/ruby2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis3.0.0/lib/redis.rb:182: warning: this causes ArgumentError in the next release
> > >       Connecting to node 192.168.1.114:6780: [ERR] Sorry, can't connect to node 192.168.1.114:6780

The envs are :
[pirate@zhangbincan src]$ gem -v
2.4.8
[pirate@zhangbincan src]$ /home/zhangbincan/tools/ruby/ruby-2.2.2/ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

“Sorry, can't connect to node 192.168.1.114:6780”, check if the port 6780 is ok.